# WPF DataGridRow.Item("xx") - Option Strict On disallows late binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, late-binding, option-strict

WPF application using DataGrid. User double-clicks on a cell, and I need to get the value of another cell in that row.

```
Dim dep As DependencyObject = DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, DependencyObject)
Dim dgRow As DataGridRow = Nothing
While dep IsNot Nothing
    If TypeOf dep Is DataGridRow Then
        dgRow = DirectCast(dep, DataGridRow)
    End If
    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep)
End While
```

So now, I have the row, I want to get the value from a specific column:

```
Dim xx As String = dgRow.Item("xx")
```

This gets me "Option Strict On disallows late binding" with no correction options.  It works fine with Option Strict Off. I have tried all the following to correct it:

```
dgRow.Item("xx").ToString
DirectCast(dgRow.Item("xx"), String)
CType(dgRow.Item("xx"), String)
```

However, the red-squiggly line remains under dgRow.Item("xx") in all these scenarios.

Appreciate any input, including alternate ways to go about this.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code that ultimately worked. I looked at the type for the Item property and it was DataRowView. Thanks to Mark's answer below.

```
dgRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(dep, DataGridRow).Item, DataRowView)
```

This allowed me to do this without the late binding error:

```
dgRow.Item("xx").ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dgRow.Item` is a property of type `Object`.  By using `dgRow.Item("xx")` you are trying to call the default property, which for `Object` doesn't exist, and therefore gives you the error you are seeing.

From the `("xx")` part, it looks like the row may be bound to some sort of dictionary.  If that is the case, you would need to cast `dgRow.Item` to the appropriate type before accessing a value from it, e.g.

```
Dim xx As String = DirectCast(dgRow.Item, Dictionary(Of String, String))("xx")
```

**UPDATE**

Reading through again, it looks like you may be binding to a `DataTable`, in which case each row would be bound to a `DataRow`, so perhaps something like this is what you need:

```
Dim xx As String = DirectCast(dgRow.Item, DataRow).Field(Of String)("xx")
```

Note, you may need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` for the [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to be available.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me fix it. I've edited my question to include my final code.